# How to determine if a Control is a Container for other Controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

I'm writing code to iterate through all controls on a form. This seemed pretty straight forward except that the `Form.Controls` collection does not include controls that are contained by other controls.

Ok, so I tried testing to see if each `ctl is ContainerControl`, and if so, recursively iterating through the controls in that container control.

Ok, but it turns out the `GroupBox` control does not derive from `ContainerControl`. It derives directly from `Control`.

Is there any generic way for my code to determine if a given control contains other controls? I assumed there would be a base type or interface that would do this but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Control.HasChildren`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.haschildren%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

> *True if this control has child controls in its collection.*

```
if (ctl.HasChildren)
{
    // true, if ctl has controls in it
}
```

Comment: Ah, right you are. In fact, I see all Controls have a `Controls` collection property. Rethinking this a bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Control> AllFormsControl = new List<Control>();
    public void InitContolList(Control nControl)
    {
        if (nControl.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Control item in nControl.Controls)
            {
                 InitContolList(item);
                AllFormsControl.Add(item);
            }

        }
      // Optional
      //AllFormsControl.Add(nControl);
    }
```

Then you may run:

```
    InitControlList(this);
```

Good luck.